# phpmailer attach file

Tags: php, mysql, email, phpmailer

How to send a file as string with phpmailer?

The file contents is stored in Mysql as a BLOB, but when sending the mail the filesize is only 2 bytes? In the database the size is about 30kb?

```
$phpmailer->AddStringAttachment(
  base64_encode($row['file_data']),
  $row['file_name'],
  'base64',
  $row['file_type']
);
```

The data is fetched directly from the mysql database without any processing...

This will display the image in the browser

```
header('Content-type: '.$row['file_type']);
echo $row['file_data'];
```

Comment: perhaps you meant `base64_encode()` rather than decode?

Comment: of course.. :) Now the file size is about 40kb, but can't still open the file... something is wrong

Comment: I've posted an answer for you. In short -- don't do any encoding at all; phpMailer does it for you already. I think that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I imagine you probably meant `base64_encode()` rather than decode?

However, my guess is that you probably don't want to be encoding it at all -- phpMailer handles the encoding internally for you, so you shouldn't need to do any base64 encoding yourself.

So I think the correct answer is simply to pass the data to the mailer without doing any encoding at all.

```
$phpmailer->AddStringAttachment(
  $row['file_data'],
  $row['file_name'],
  'base64',
  $row['file_type']
);
```

Hope that helps.